# PHP use current function in foreach

Tags: php, reference

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach($arr as $key => $row) {
    echo current($arr);
}

//output is 22222, why?
```

Why the result is not 12345?

Comment: Have you read the docs for [current](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.current.php) ? You're effectively asking about the internals of foreach (in what way and when it advances the pointer - or not).

Comment: maybe because we're all confused here

Comment: @AD7six Then I would delete that comment

Answer (score 0):

if you want the output to be 12345:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```